# data-ng-repeat doesn't work well here

Tags: angularjs

What is wrong with my code? It has to show all the NAME, but it doesn't work well

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    DemoApp = angular.module("DemoApp", []);
    DemoApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.Customer = [{ Fname: 'Alireza', City: 'Tehran' }, { Fname: 'Ali', City: 'Tabriz' }, { Fname: 'Ehsan', City: 'Abadan'}];
    });
    DemoApp.controller();
</script>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="DemoApp"> 
<div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="cust in Customer">{{cust.Fname}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Im new in angularjs , plz help me to figure it out :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capitalization mismatch Fname != FName

http://jsfiddle.net/cdCqu/

HTML

```
<body data-ng-app="DemoApp"> 
<div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="cust in Customer">{{cust.Fname}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

JS

```
angular.module("DemoApp", []).controller('SimpleController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.Customer = [{ Fname: 'Alireza', City: 'Tehran' }, { Fname: 'Ali', City: 'Tabriz' }, { Fname: 'Ehsan', City: 'Abadan'}];
    });
```

Comment: dta-ng-repeat != data-ng-repeat :)

Comment: How can i reach to the $scope data in my <li>

Comment: Your problems were three fold the two syntax errors and you were calling the controller which you shouldn't do explicitly, having ng-controller is enough to invoke it.  Any descendants in the DOM will have access to the properties of the $scope

Comment: Merci a vous , Tres Bien . :D

Comment: Hmm I think your welcome :) and probably good morning I need to get to bed here though, have a good one.

Answer (score 1):

try this jsFiddle , also you do not need data attribute as well as FName must be Fname , you donot need to append data with ng attributes

```
just remove data attribute
```

http://jsfiddle.net/imsaurabh/K6qwQ/

Comment: data attribute doesn't hurt and allows for validation if you're into that sort of thing